# How to save values in pandas dataframe after editing some values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe which looks like this (It contains dummy data) -

[image]

I want to remove the text which occurs after "_________" identifier in each of the cells. I have written the code as follows (Logic: Adding a new column containing NaN and saving the edited values in that column) -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'Desktop\Trial.xlsx')

NaN = np.nan
df["Body2"] = NaN

substring = "____________"

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if substring in row["Body"]:
        split_string = row["Body"].split(substring,1)
        row["Body2"] = split_string[0]

print(df)
```

But the Body2 column still displays NaN and not the edited values.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) instead of a loop.

Comment: use `df["Body2"]=df["Body"].str.split(substring,1).str[0] `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if substring in row["Body"]:
       split_string = row["Body"].split(substring,1)
       #row["Body2"] = split_string[0] # instead use below line         
       df.at[index,'Body2'] = split_string[0]`
```

Make use of at to modify the value

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through the rows, do the operation on all rows at once.  You can use expand to split the values into multiple columns, which I think is what you want.

```
substring = "____________"
df = pd.DataFrame({'Body': ['a____________b', 'c____________d', 'e____________f', 'gh']})
df[['Body1', 'Body2']] = df['Body'].str.split(substring, expand=True)
print(df)
#              Body Body1 Body2
# 0  a____________b     a     b
# 1  c____________d     c     d
# 2  e____________f     e     f
# 3              gh    gh  None
```

Comment: Excellent - could you vote for my answer?